# Query in Kibana Panel

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm working on a dashboard that uses Kibana. The dashboard has two panels: A table and a Histogram. My current data set has ~4,500 documents. However, it will grow significantly. I've noticed that the histogram factors in all of the data. At the same time, the table only shows the most recent 500 records. I would really like to figure out how to get my table to show all of the records.

Does anyone know how to do this? If so, how? It has me totally confused.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

To see more than the default 500 records click on the gear-wheel icon within your table (called "Table Settings") and go to tab "Paging"

"Per Page" x  "Page limit" = "Pageable"

default is

"100" x "5" = "500"

Comment: Is there a way to see all records?

Comment: Make sure your page size ("Per page" field) is not too large ("too large" = on the order of 10,000 or greater for me) or you may hang your browser.  Similarly, if the number of total records is too high ("too large" = on the order of 100,000 or greater for me), you might hang your browser when attempting to compile a per-field "micro analysis" (available by clicking a field in the left-hand column). Don't learn this the hard way like I did :(